# How to get locale language using I18n React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, internationalization, i18next

I am trying to get the locale of the users mobile so it translates some texts from my app to the corresponding language (to the language the mobile is set to which is Finnish). The languages that are currently supported are English and Finnish. The issue is that the text that should be in Finnish is displayed always in English even if it should be displayed in Finnish. I have created both en.json and fi.json files like so:

en.json:

```
{
    "huomio": "Warning!"
}
```

fi.json:

```
{
    "huomio": "Huomio!"
}
```

This is the file that I have created that should translate the header of the screen to the corresponding language:

index.js:

```
import I18n from "ex-react-native-i18n";
import { Localization } from "expo-localization";
import fi from './fi.json';
import en from './en.json';

I18n.translations = {
    fi,
    en
}

const getLanguage = async() => {
    try {
        const choice = await Localization.locale
        I18n.locale = choice.substr(0, 2)
        I18n.initAsync()
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Unable to get locale')
    }
}

getLanguage()

export function t(name) {
    return I18n.t(name)
}
```

This is the way I am trying to do the translation of the header of the screen in the corresponding file:

```
<Text style={styles.textHeader} >{t('huomio')}</Text>
```

The only thing I know about the issue is that the getLanguage function always catches the error and the error message is printed to the console. I would be really grateful to get help for this problem.

Comment: Your `getLanguage()` function is `async`, but you don't call it with `await` or treat the return value as a Promise (which it will be).

Comment: I have already tried to call it with await but the result is still the same.